# Spring-Cloud-Contract: Intellij IDEA, publishStubsToScm: Unable to determine git repository commit id ... Auth fail

Tags: github, intellij-idea, spring-cloud-contract

*./gradlew publishStubsToScm* fails to push stubs to github repo.

Beyond that, I can pull/push via IDEA to stubs-repo, I can pull/push via the terminal to stubs-repo with passphrase.

Gradle configuration:

```
contracts {
    testFramework = "JUNIT5"
    baseClassForTests = "com.example.BaseTContainers"
    contractDependency {
        stringNotation = "${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"
    }
    contractRepository {

        repositoryUrl = "git://git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git"
    }
    contractsMode = "REMOTE"
}
```

LOCAL mode works fine and stubs are generated in the local maven repo, but REMOTE mode fails.

```
Execution failed for task ':copyContracts'.
> Exception occurred while cloning repo


Unable to determine git repository commit id
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git: remote hung up unexpectedly
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:189)
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git: remote hung up unexpectedly
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:153)

...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshSessionFactory.getSession(org.eclipse.jgit.transport.URIish, org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProvider, org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS, int)" because "this.sch" is null
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:281)


* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':copyContracts'.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred while cloning repo
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.GitRepo.cloneProject(GitRepo.java:128)

...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git: Auth fail
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:153)
```

**UPDATE:**
After manually pushing to contracts repo, Consumer side working fine (cloning repo to local dir)

**more logs:**

```
Unable to determine git repository commit id
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:189)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractsCopyTask.discoverGitCommitId(ContractsCopyTask.java:521)


Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.example:service:jar:stubs:2021.0.0 from/to remote0 (git://git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git): Cannot access git://git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory


 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherStubDownloader] Resolving artifact [com.example:service:jar:stubs:2021.0.0] using remote repositories [remote0 (git://git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git, default, releases+snapshots)]
 [DEBUG] [shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider] Could not obtain transporter factory for remote0 (git://git@github.com:example/contracts-stubs.git, default, releases+snapshots)
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Unsupported transport protocol git
```

Comment: Do you have an ssh agent running? 

# to run the agent
eval `ssh-agent`
# to store the pass in the agent
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: thank you @Marcin Grzejszczak for fast answer. yes, eval returns agent's PID. 
Looks like stubs cannot be uploaded to the remote repo. Should I maybe push the first version of stubs there manually? Adding logs in the next comment

Comment: updated logs in the question body. And question #2, I cannot override the branch to checkout 
contracts {
gitBranch = "main"
} which format should it be for Gradle? git.branch mentioned in docs doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/gradle-project.html#gradle-pushing-stubs-to-scm . contractsProperties = ["git.branch": "main" ]

Comment: able to set the property, thanx!

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak could it be that I get `NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshSessionFactory.getSession` because of deprecated org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch? (org.springframework.cloud.contract:3.1.2) <https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1106995&goto=1838158&#msg_1838158>

Comment: No idea really - I haven't seen this issue nor do I see your project